# NodeJS route that makes a mysql query don't pass every parameters in the query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a variable in which I store the request's body, a query variable then I make the query with the "conn.query" function. Here's the code:

```
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    //get the request's body in a variable
    const thebody = req.body;

    //get connection
    const conn = await pool.getConnection();

    //create a new query
    const query = 'INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';

    //executing the query
    const result = await conn.query(query, thebody.username, thebody.email, thebody.password);
    res.status(200).json(result);
})
```

Here's the error:

```
  text: 'Parameter at position 2 is not set',
  sql: "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?) - parameters:['filou']",
  fatal: false,
  errno: 45016,
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  code: 'ER_MISSING_PARAMETER'
}
```

And here's the body of the request sent via postman:

```
{
    "username" : "filou",
    "password" : "azerty",
    "email" : "email.com"
}
```

I tried to put `thebody.username, thebody.email and thebody.password` in brackets [...] but I get another error "do not know how to stringify". Do you guys any ideas what's going on?

Comment: console.log(thebody)

Comment: @Evert I added the console.log right after the declaration of the body. Here's the result: { username: 'filou', password: 'azerty', email: 'email.com' }

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of query should be an array with parameters, so try something like:
`conn.query(query, [thebody.username, thebody.email, thebody.password]);`

Comment: Hello! I did try what you're suggesting. I get an error : TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt. I don't know why though :( do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you get this error in the query or in the last line with result ?  
In the last line you are serializing all the response. If you are using mysqljs/mysql you can just get the inserted id, and return just it.  
Try this:  
`    res.status(200).json({id: result.insertId}); `